# Resource's "time cached" value is incorrect when using the cache put API

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache, service-worker

I am using a service worker to cache a custom response. I am not able to clone an existing response or use `cache.add`.

When I cache the new response, the "time cached" column always shows `12/31/1969, 3:59:59 PM`.

You can see this in action by executing the following in the console.

```
var cache = await caches.open('my-cache');

var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-type', 'application/javascript; charset=utf-8');

var responseData = {
    status: 200,
    statusText: 'OK',
    headers: headers
};

cache.put('hello.js', new Response('alert("hi!");', responseData));
```

If you look at the cached file, you'll see that the time cached is incorrect:

[image: the time cached is incorrect].

I have experimented with specifying various response headers, including `Age`, `Cache-Control`, `Date`, and `Expires`. Nothing that I have added corrects this value.

Any thoughts on why this is, and how to correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with Chrome's DevTools, rather than an issue with your code. I've filed https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=845629 on your behalf to track it.